# Serializing a generic list of CustomType does not serialize elements' variables

Tags: c#, serialization

This is my data class :

```
public class Data
{
    [Serializable]
    public List<SomeType> myList = new List<SomeType>(20);
    private string dataPath = "SomePath";

    void Save()
    {
        using(FileStream fs = File.Create(dataPath))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter()
            formatter.Serialize(fs, myList);
        }
    }

    void Load()
    {
        using(FileStream fs = File.Open(dataPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            myList = (List<SomeType>) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the SomeType class :

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeType
{
    public bool isUsed;
}
```

I realized that when I load my file, isUsed variable of all elements turn false even though I'm sure I turn most of them true during runtime. What am I doing wrong here? Does it have anything to do with isUsed not being a property?

Comment: It looks like in your Save function you are creating a FileStream but not using it.

Comment: Your could doesn't compile. You aren't passing any stream to `formatter.Serialize`

Comment: But the file it's supposed to create doesn't seem to be non existent.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's just that I forgot to type it in here. I am actually passing fs to Serialize function in my actual code. I'll correct that right away.

Comment: `formatter.Serialize(myList);` This shouldn't compile. You have to pass a `Stream` as the first argument

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SomeType
    {
        public bool isUsed;
    }

    public class Data
    {
        //removed because its not permitted here,you already have sometype serializable...
        public List<SomeType> myList = new List<SomeType>(20);
        private string dataPath = "SomePath";

        public void Save()
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create(dataPath))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(fs, myList);

            }
            //just for testing purposes i cleared the list at this point...
            myList.Clear();
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(dataPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                myList = (List<SomeType>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to keep appending items to the file in your save method instead of File.Create(),place this:

```
File.Open(dataPath,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write)
```

Even if it does not exist it will be created due to filemode.append.

you should have passed the stream to the serialize method,also its not a good thing to have public fields like your myList,you could create a property for it at minimum.

Comment: Excuse me but I couldn't notice any difference other than the unnecessary attribute you removed.

Comment: this line in the save method - formatter.Serialize(fs, myList);. And the attribute is not about unnecessary its invalid there...

Comment: Yes, I'm so sorry I forgot to pass fs to my Serialize method. As I stated above, it's just a mistake that I made here. I fixed it.

Comment: please provide the code where you initialize the class,populate the list and save & load operations.